# Label does not populate

Tags: c#

I have this code to receive a number from user through a text box, then use that value and two values from a SQL table and perform a simple calculation. I debugged and get no errors but my label in gridview does not populate. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
protected void Calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Divide], [Calc] FROM [Parrts] WHERE (([Region] = 'East Coast') AND ([Model] = @Model) AND ([SashSize] = @SashSize) AND ([Operation] = @Operation) AND ([PartDesc] = @PartDesc) AND ([Description] = @Description) AND ([Lites] =@Lites))", conn);

    SqlParameter Model = new SqlParameter("@Model", ddModel.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(Model);
    SqlParameter SashSize = new SqlParameter("@SashSize", ddSashSize.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(SashSize);
    SqlParameter Operation = new SqlParameter("@Operation", ddOperation.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(Operation);
    SqlParameter Part = new SqlParameter("@PartDesc", ddPart.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(Part);
    SqlParameter Color = new SqlParameter("@Description",ddColor.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(Color);
    SqlParameter Lites = new SqlParameter("@Lites",ddLites.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(Lites);

    conn.Open();
    cmd.Connection = conn;

    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        Int32 Divide = (int)rdr["Divide"];
        double Calc = (double)rdr["Calc"];

        int HW = Convert.ToInt32(length_txt.Text);
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridViewAMI.Rows)
        {
            string Length = ((Label)row.FindControl("Length")).Text;
            Response.Write(Length);
            Length = ((HW / Divide) - Calc).ToString();
        }
    }
    rdr.Close();
    cmd.Dispose();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: All you do is set a local string variable called `Length`. This has no side effect whatsoever for you `GridViewAMI`, or its `Rows` object.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: Why `([Operation] = @Operation) AND ([PartDesc] = @PartDesc)` but not `[Operation] = @Operation AND [PartDesc] = @PartDesc`? I guess (bad) Pascal background. This is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't see you populating the Label again maybe this helps:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridViewAMI.Rows)
{
    // Get the Label safely so you can manipulate it later
    Label rowLabel = row.FindControl("Length") as Label;

    // If you - for whatever reason - can't get the Label, skip this row
    if(rowlabel == null)
        continue;

    string length = rowLabel.Text;
    Response.Write(length);
    length = ((HW / Divide) - Calc).ToString();

    // Populate the Label with the new Data
    rowLabel.Text = length;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept the most fitting answer by clicking on the check mark and add preferably add a tag to what UI Framework you're using (as @TaW mentioned in his comment)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridViewAMI.Rows)
{
    Label lbl = (Label)row.FindControl("Length");
    string length = lbl.Text;
    Response.Write(length);
    length = ((HW / Divide) - Calc).ToString();
    lbl.Text = length;
}
```

You forgot to put the text back in the `Label`.

Comment: Amazing IDarkCoder, that worked. Thank you so much everyone for your help, especially IDarkCoder. Hopefully I will return the favor some day when I get better at code writing. :).